# Is the following statement true on $L^0$ spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $X,Y\in L^0(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ two random variables taking values in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that:
$$\int_{A} f(X(\omega)) P(d\omega) = \int_{A} f(Y(\omega)) dP(\omega)$$
for all $A\in \mathcal{F}$ and all Lipschitz continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then
$$X=Y, \quad P-a.s.?$$
In other notation this is like saying:
$$E[f(X)] = E[f(Y)] \quad \forall f\in Lip(\mathbb{R}) \Rightarrow X=Y,\quad P-a.s.$$

Could we also relax it to all $f$ continuous and bounded (not necessarily Lipschitz)?

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot to say what $A$ was. Actually I think you can just write $\Omega$ there yes..

Comment: Actually, you're not relaxing the condition if you take f continuous and bounded, because there exist continuous bounded functions that are not Lipschitz (take $\min(1,\sqrt{|x|})$ )

Answer (score 1):

Under the further hypothesis that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ is a [standard probability space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space), I believe that this is true even if we restrict to only one $f$, namely $f(x) = x$.

Recall the [Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem). To apply that here, assume that $\Omega =[0, 1]$, $\mathcal{F}$ is the completed $\sigma$-algebra, and $P$ is Lebesgue measure. Equivalently, we can assume that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ is mod $0$ isomorphic to that space, which is equivalent to the hypothesis that the space is standard.

From there, we have that $$ X(\omega) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \int_{B_\epsilon (\omega)} X dP = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon} \int_{B_\epsilon (\omega)} Y dP = Y(\omega) $$ where the first and third equality are almost surely true by Lebesgue differentiation, and the second by the hypothesis.

So, with the probability space standard, this is true, but for more unusual situations, you'd need some way to get from integrals to function values, and Lebesgue Differentiation is the only method to do that that I am aware of.

Comment: Aha... I see!! I understand the reasoning but now I'm curious to know what happens when $A=\Omega$ is fixed, because then you can not conclude the same. In other words, only if you look at the integrals of continuous and bounded functions of $X$ and $Y$, if they agree are then $X$ and $Y$ equal as well? :)

Comment: This answer is not true. If $f(x) = x$ would suffice, the conclusion would be that $X = Y$ whenever $E(X) = E(Y)$. This is obviously wrong.

Comment: @gerw: The hypothesis is not that a single integral of the two functions is equal, it is that the integrals over all measurable sets are equal. This is much stronger than $E(X)=E(Y)$ which depends on only a single integral.

Comment: @gerw: the second hypothesis presented in the question isn't the same as the first. Its considerably weaker, and is what Martingalo was asking in his comment here. My argument certainly doesn't apply to it, and I believe the conclusion is false there. In particular, if you have $\Omega=[0,1]^2$ with its usual structure, and $X(x, y) = x$ and $Y(x, y) =y$, then $\iint_\Omega f(X) d \lambda d \lambda = \int_{[0, 1]} f d\lambda = \iint_\Omega f(Y) d \lambda d \lambda$ for all measurable $f$. You need to be able to limit the integrals to particular sets, or these sorts of products will confound.